# SAS raw data read--line pointers with inconsistent lines and embedded headers

Tags: file-io, sas

The raw data I want to read not only runs across several different lines but also doesn't have the same number of lines per record. To further complicate things it also has headers that appear in the middle of the file after every page that ruin everything.

```
 Time: 1:47pm                                      Item Master Report For 06/06/2013                                 Report: GMRIMMSB

Item Type: Nonstock

Item  Asset  Inven  Dsp   ---Order---  ---Primary----                           Substute     Contract     Hazd   Count     
Stat  Class  Class  Unt   Unit   Conv   Loc    Vendor        Manufacturer Nbr   Item Nbr      Number      Flag   Cycle  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ITEM     20049 TEST PNEUMONIA S LATEX ZL22 (30859001)
 A    0173    6      PK     PK       1   NSL   2431       R30859001                                                     
     Vendor  1:      2431 FISHER SCIENTIFIC COMPANY                 2:      2658 REMEL
             3:       536 ABBOTT LABS - DIAGNOSTIC DIVISION         4:      1404 MUREX DIAGNOSTICS INC.

  ITEM     20051 ANTIGEN BACTER. WELLCOGEN ZL26 B1901-51
 A    0173    6      PK     PK       1   NSL   2431       30859602                                                      
     Vendor  1:      2431 FISHER SCIENTIFIC COMPANY                 2:      3804 CARDINAL HEALTH-ALLEGIANCE
             3:      2658 REMEL                                     4:       536 ABBOTT LABS - DIAGNOSTIC DIVISION
             5:      1404 MUREX DIAGNOSTICS INC.

  ITEM     20053 FILM DUPLICATING 10X12
 I    0173    14     BX     BX       1   NSX   1335       112010                                                        
     Vendor  1:      1335 AGFA CORPORATION

  ITEM     20055 FILM HTU 10 X 12
 I    0173    14     BX     BX       1   NSX   1335       094010                                                        
     Vendor  1:      1335 AGFA CORPORATION

  ITEM     20056 FILM HTU 8 X 10
 I    0173    14     BX     BX       1   NSX   1335       094008                                                        
     Vendor  1:      1335 AGFA CORPORATION

  ITEM     20057 SOL AXSYM FLUIDIES CHECK (09A3401)
 A    0173    119    BX     BX       1   NSL   536                                                                      
     Vendor  1:       536 ABBOTT LABS - DIAGNOSTIC DIVISION

  ITEM     20058 FILM DUPLICATING 8 X 10
 I    0173    14     BX     BX       1   NSX   1335       112008                                                        
     Vendor  1:      1335 AGFA CORPORATION

  ITEM     20059 FILM HTU 14 X 17
 I    0173    14     BX     BX       1   NSX   1335       094014                                                        
     Vendor  1:      1335 AGFA CORPORATION
Item  Asset  Inven  Dsp   ---Order---  ---Primary----                           Substute     Contract     Hazd   Count     
Stat  Class  Class  Unt   Unit   Conv   Loc    Vendor        Manufacturer Nbr   Item Nbr      Number      Flag   Cycle  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  ITEM     20060 FILM HTU 30 X 35
 I    0173    14     BX     BX       1   NSX   1335       094030                                                        
     Vendor  1:      1335 AGFA CORPORATION

  ITEM     20061 FILM HTU 14 X 14
 I    0173    14     BX     BX       1   NSX   1335       094001                                                        
     Vendor  1:      1335 AGFA CORPORATION
```

Here is the code I have working with (in SAS studio)....

```
libname mylib '/folders/myfolders/';

data myfile;
    length itm $ 4 itemnum 5 itemdesc $ 40 inac $ 2 assetcl $ 4 invcl 3 dspunit $ 2
ordunit $ 2 convr 4 loc $ 4 vndnum 4 manufnum $ 20 vendinfo $ 80; 
    infile '/folders/myfolders/ItemstrSM.txt' missover;
    input #1 itm $ itemnum itemdesc $ &
          #2 inac $ assetcl $ invcl dspunit $ ordunit $ convr loc $ vndnum manufnum 
          #3 vendinfo & $ ; 
run;

proc print data=myfile noobs;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to routinely handle lots of this file, you can simply use a text editor to solve the problem.

1. Replace the page head to blank.
2. Replace '\nITEM' to '###ITEM'
3. Replace '\n' to space
4. Replace '###' to '\n'

Now you have one entry per line in the text file.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround you can use to deal with the repeated header rows is to use something along the lines of the following before your main input statement:

```
input @;
if _infile_ = "Header row text" then delete;
```

This loads the whole line into `_infile_` without populating any variables and holds it for processing by your main input statement (provided that it isn't a header row).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the same formating you've shown us there continues, and that there are no more than 6 vendors for each item:

```
data test(drop=itm);
  length itm $4 itemnum 8 itemdesc $132
            inac $1 assetcl invcl 8 dspunit ordunit $2 convr 8 loc $3 vndnum 8 manufnum $132;
  infile "c:\users\c41928\documents\egreadin.txt" missover lrecl=32767 truncover;
  input itm $ @;
     if itm="ITEM" then 
      do;
        input itemnum itemdesc $ / 
                inac $ assetcl $ invcl dspunit $ ordunit $ convr loc $ vndnum manufnum /
                vendinfo1 $132.;
        if index(vendinfo1,"2:") then 
            input itm $ @;
            if itm="3:" then
            do;
              input @1 vendinfo2 $132.;
              input itm $ @;
              if  itm = "5:" then
                do;
                   input @1 vendinfo3 $132.; 
                   output;
                 end;
              else output;
            end; 
         else output;
       end;
    else delete;
run;
```

If there is a unknown, and possibly infinite, number of vendors, then an itterative do loop would be more suitable. Otherwise, if there is a known number of vendors higher than 6, more do loops could be added.

Anyway, it's not very pretty but it works.

Comment: I'm going to double check character vs numeric variables and resubmit tonight ... Thanks for the help

Comment: Do add any additional info if there is any

Comment: That works! Vend 1 and 2 are in the same field, but it's all more or less there. Thank you, reps added....